# Poisson matlab pde code for different $\delta (x)$ and $\delta (y)$

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I found a function online [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/matlab/poisson.m) for a function to compute for the same delta x and delta y. I am trying to edit it to be able to handle different $\delta (x)$ and $\delta (y)$.

Here are the [changes](https://www.diffchecker.com/Sz4WhNy3) that I have made so far. It works when I have $m=n$, but that makes the deltax and deltay the same too. I can't figure out where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are getting x and y wrong. Matlab uses rows and columns which can be counterintuitive if you are used to x,y for example.

Comment: I can take a look at that again. I feel like I have it the correct way, and I have tried it the other way I think. Thank you though I will try and take a closer look

Comment: I'm sorry my brain is completely nulled on exercises. I could build my own solver in 5 mins but for some reason can't put in much effort for premade ones.

Comment: No worries at all :)

Comment: You should post your code in your question and give a link to the diff. Line 17 is a bust as are lines 44:59. You need both an `I` and a `J` vector for the $2$ different sizes as well as an `e` and `f` vector. `T` should get [e -2*e e] and either `m` or `n` but not the min. Similarly, `S` gets [e -2*e e] over [-1 0 1] and the other of `m` or `n`. Then you have to divide each Kronecker product by its own `h^2`. And I haven't look further into your code.

Comment: Thank you. line 17 was given in the book im reading as a hint. So I want to use that. I will look into the other suggestions. I appreicate your time.

Comment: @user5713492 Thank you so much! I think I got it! :D

Comment: I got the error to be O(h) but I am wanting it to be O(h^2) like the normal five point code. Do you think I still have an error in it?